# What are the correct time stamps for r auto.arima prediction?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to predict some macroeconomic series with r auto.arima. 
This is the code I use:

```
model_fit = auto.arima(data, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE)
prediction = fitted(model_fit)
print(data)
print(prediction)
```

the output is:

```
> print(data)
       Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
1999  0.9029963  1.0156890  1.1867020  1.5719140
2000  2.0067800  1.9615760  2.2470900  2.5198470
2001  2.1401040  2.9407880  2.4341130  2.1403400
2002  2.5637690  2.1126460  2.1070180  2.3041870
2003  2.3093520  1.9977380  2.0719100  2.0940880
2004  1.7487290  2.3240540  2.2922990  2.3406600
2005  2.0721600  2.0425360  2.3130890  2.3588480
2006  2.3445580  2.4853510  2.1981040  1.8023280
2007  1.8980200  1.9109010  1.9092900  2.9328540
2008  3.4199780  3.7011940  3.9163310  2.3477840
2009  1.0112570  0.2069567 -0.3620303  0.4282966
2010  1.1070920  1.5942610  1.7186250  2.0275400
2011  2.4790400  

> print(prediction)
       Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
1999  1.3812718  1.0955290  1.3415711  1.6519519
2000  2.0552300  2.2757984  2.2110367  2.3541009
2001  2.5865675  2.3494052  2.8218531  2.3474635
2002  2.2046983  2.0644884  2.3801052  2.1063136
2003  2.0630790  2.2841777  2.1292972  1.8625121
2004  1.9513986  1.9568159  2.3676378  2.2579986
2005  2.4307846  1.7551040  2.0206889  2.2715579
2006  2.6566236  2.0881174  2.2141798  2.0744364
2007  1.8995575  1.5632795  2.0096422  2.1640363
2008  3.0225346  3.3082346  3.6079884  3.0474864
2009  1.6090527  0.1043498 -0.2002444  0.3544487
2010  1.3420635  1.7475707  2.2098229  1.9617557 
2011  2.3519234
```

The prediction's time stamps correspond to the time stamps of the data.

Now, `fitted` produces one step ahead predictions. I understand this as: using the real values of data up to time `t` produce a prediction for time `t+1`. For example `1999Q1` is used to predict `1999Q2`. Based on this assumption I was expecting to see a predicted value for `2011Q2`, but there isn't one.

My question is: Are the time stamps in the predicted series correct? Is `prediction[1999Q1]`, the model's estimate for `data[1999Q1]`?

Also is this affected by difference order `D`? And if the time stamps are correct, why is there no prediction for `2011Q1`?

I need to produce a plot of the true values and the predicted values and want to make sure they align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata <- read.xlsx("C:/../Data.xlsx")
data_ts <- ts(mydata$Data, start=c(1999,1), frequency = 4)
print(data_ts)
mydata_aa<- auto.arima(data_ts)
print(mydata_aa)
mydata_aa_pred <- forecast:::forecast.Arima(mydata_aa, h=10)
print(mydata_aa_pred)
```

Have used the above codes and I was able to get the prediction starting from 2011 Q2. As I am also new, i am unable to paste the output. Hope the above code will be helpful. You need forecast package to execute the above command.If you haven't downloaded or need help use the below code.

```
install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)
library(forecast)
```